# Override bean in Spring Boot 2.1 slice test with nested TestConfiguration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I just migrated an application from Spring Boot 1.x to 2.1. One of my test is failing due to a change to [bean overriding default](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.1-Release-Notes#bean-overriding)

I tried to set `spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding` to `true` but it's not working.

You can reproduce the issue with the following classes:

```
@Configuration
public class ClockConfig {

    @Bean
    public Clock clock() {
        return Clock.systemUTC();
    }

}

@Service
public class MyService {

    private final Clock clock;

    public MyService(Clock clock) {
        this.clock = clock;
    }

    public Instant now() {
        return clock.instant();
    }

}

@RestController
public class MyResource {

    private final MyService myService;

    public MyResource(MyService myService) {
        this.myService = myService;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Instant> now() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(myService.now());
    }
}
```

The failing test. The `clock()` method is never called with Spring Boot 2.1 whereas it was with Spring Boot 1.5 or Spring Boot 2.0.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(MyResource.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = MyService.class)
public class ResourceTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Test
    public void test() {
    }

    @TestConfiguration
    static class TestConfig {
        @Bean
        public Clock clock() {
            return Clock.fixed(Instant.MIN, ZoneId.of("Z"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have problem with starting application context? I tried your example at my machine and I cannot even start context.

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify ContextConfiguration annotation. It should be: `@ContextConfiguration(classes = {MyService.class,ClockConfig.class})` .
You explicitly specified which config you would like to import in your test with @ContextConfiguration annotation so your `@TestConfiguration` is not loaded at all. If you exclude your `@ContextConfiguration` it can work. Since you removed configuration of `MyService`, you have to provide `MyService` bean in your test config. Try this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(MyResource.class)
public class DemoApplicationTests {

   @Autowired
   private MockMvc mvc;

   @Test
   public void test() {
   }

   @TestConfiguration
   static class TestConfig {
       @Bean
       public Clock clock() {
           return Clock.fixed(Instant.MIN, ZoneId.of("Z"));
       }

       @Bean
       public MyService service() {
           return new MyService(clock());
       }
   }
  }
```

Comment: No, the goal is not to use the `ClockConfig` but the `TestConfig`